# Is there any need to use @1x images if app is creating above iPhone 4+ devices?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating my app for only iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.
I got some info as mentioned below:-

1- Normal device which terms to 1 pixel = 1 point **@1x (Older iPhone and iPad devices)**

2- Retina device which terms to 4 pixels(2 x 2) = 1 point **@2x (iPhone 4+)**

3- Retina iPhone6 and iPad which terms to 9 pixels (3 x 3) = 1 point **@3x (iPhone6+)**

Please clarify that is there any need to add @1x images in **Images.xcassets**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For iPad 2 you need 1x resolution pics. So for that situation you need 1x images in your image assets but in case you are not officially supporting iPad and iPhones above 4 then you don't need those. But an iPhone only app runs on iPad too so you need to include the images in 1x resolution. In case you are supporting iOS 10 + only then in that case you don't need 1x images as iPad 2 does not support iOS 10.

Comment: All iPhone-only apps must run as-is on the iPad so there is no such thing as "not supporting iPads". But the iPad 2 only supports iOS 9 so if the app only supports iOS 10 and later then you don't need to deal with 1x images.

Comment: Suppose that the target is not a universal app. It will run it is not built keeping iPad in mind. Anyways if the deployment target is above iOS 10 then there is no confusion in that case.

Comment: @rmaddy improved my answer.

Comment: If you don't then the 1x devices will just display scaled down versions of the 2x images so you don't NEED to include them... but you should.